# How to define a self-defined object that includes other self-defined objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to define a object that include other self-define objects in Javascript, for example:

```
object1 {
    p1 : "",
    p2 : "",
     ...
}

object2 {
    p3 : "",
    p4 :   Array of object1,
   ...
}
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor function for object1, and create instances in the array of p4 on object2. 
If you do not want to use a constructor function for object1, but rather use the literal object notation as you did in your example, you can use Object.create().

```
object1 = {
  p1: "",
  p2: ""
}
object2 = {
  p3: "",
  p4: [Object.create(object1),Object.create(object1),Object.create(object1)]
}
```

Or ....

```
object2 = {
  p3: "",
  p4: []
}
p4.push(Object.create(object1));
p4.push(Object.create(object1));
```

However keep in mind that while the first answer uses a constructor and thus creates the properties in the object as instance properties, the Object.create() uses the original object as the prototype for the derived objects.